# TIdHTTP::OnAuthorization in multithreaded application

Tags: multithreading, authentication, c++builder, indy10

I'm writing a DLL in C++Builder XE6 to communicate with a REST server. The DLL creates a `TThread`-derived thread to do GET requests in the background, using `TIdHTTP`. The DLL also exports functions to do GET and POST requests in the main thread, using a second `TIdHTTP` instance. Both `TIdHTTP` instances can trigger an `OnAuthorization` event if the server returns a 401 (Unauthorized) response code.

I've written a function to prompt the user for credentials, called `PromptForCredentials()`, which shows a standard Windows credentials dialog. This function is called if either instance triggers an `OnAuthorization` event (in the background thread via `Synchronize()`). Only thing is, the background thread can trigger an `OnAuthorization` event while the user is being prompted for credentials during an `OnAuthorization` event in the main thread and vice versa. This would show two copies of the credentials dialog at the same time.

I can use `TCriticalSection` to prevent calling `PromptForCredentials()` twice, so that only one copy of the credentials dialog is shown at a time. That way, if the main thread prompts for credentials, the background thread will block when it also tries to prompt for credentials and vice versa.

If authentication is successful in one thread, the other thread should use the same credentials instead of prompting the user a second time. I can do this by copying the `Username` and `Password` properties from one `TIdHTTP` instance to the other, either at the end of the `OnAuthorization` event or after the request is completed. However, if a second `OnAuthorization` event occurs during the first one, the user is still prompted twice for credentials. AFAIK, `TCriticalSection` doesn't provide a way to check if the lock is already acquired. Otherwise, I could wait until the lock is released and use the credentials without prompting a second time.

How do I prevent prompting the user for credentials twice in succession?

**Update**

The documentation for `TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer::BeginWrite()` states:

> As a rule, a thread should always discard previous samples from
> protected memory after promoting a read lock to a write lock. However,
> the calling thread can determine whether a state change has occurred
> by examining return value of BeginWrite: True if the protected memory
> has not been written to by another thread or **False if another thread
> may have modified the protected memory**.

So, here's what I tried:

```
#include <System.SysUtils.hpp>

TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer* Lock = NULL;

void GetCreds (const String Caption)
{
    Lock->BeginRead();

    try
    {
        // Retrieve globally stored credentials here.

        bool Prompt = Lock->BeginWrite();

        try
        {
            if (Prompt)
                Application->MessageBox(_T("Prompt"), Caption.c_str(), MB_OK);
            else
                Application->MessageBox(_T("Use"), Caption.c_str(), MB_OK);
        }
        __finally
        {
            Lock->EndWrite();
        }
    }
    __finally
    {
        Lock->EndRead();
    }
}

class TMyThread : public TThread
{
    typedef TThread inherited;

    protected:
                void __fastcall DoTask  ();
        virtual void __fastcall Execute ();

    public:
        __fastcall TMyThread () : inherited(true) {}
};

void __fastcall TMyThread::DoTask ()
{
    GetCreds("Thread");
}

void __fastcall TMyThread::Execute ()
{
    while (!Terminated)
    {
        Sleep(2000);

        if (Terminated)
            break;

        Synchronize(DoTask);
    }
}

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click (TObject *Sender)
{
    Lock = new TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer();

    try
    {
        TMyThread* Thread = new TMyThread();

        try
        {
            Thread->Start();

            GetCreds("Main");
        }
        __finally
        {
            Thread->Terminate();
            Thread->WaitFor();

            delete Thread;
        }
    }
    __finally
    {
        delete Lock;
    }
}
```

When I click `Button1`, I get a message box with caption "Main" and text "Prompt". As expected, the user is prompted for credentials the first time.

With the message box still open, the background thread kicks in after 2 seconds with a (synchronized) call to `GetCreds()`. Since the main thread acquired a write lock, you would expect the background thread to be blocked on the `BeginRead()` call and no second message box to appear. However, I still get a second message box with caption "Thread" and text "Prompt".

To test, I switched from `TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer` to `TCriticalSection`.

`GetCreds()` now looks like this:

```
void GetCreds (const String Caption)
{
    Lock->Acquire();

    try
    {
        Application->MessageBox(_T("Prompt"), Caption.c_str(), MB_OK);
    }
    __finally
    {
        Lock->Release();
    }
}
```

I still get two message boxes, while I should only see the one from the main thread.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update 2**

As Remy pointed out, `TCriticalSection` locks are reentrant for the thread that has the lock. If I call `GetCreds()` directly in the thread, i.e. without `Synchronize()`, the code in my first update works as expected.

I also found that `TCriticalSection` has a `TryEnter()` method, whose return value can be used to check if another thread currently has the lock.

Comment: I would store the credentials globally, protected by its own lock. Have each thread enter the lock when authorization is needed, and keep it locked until the request is finished, that way it can prompt the user each time a new Authorization event is fired. If the request succeeds, update the stored credentials before unlocking. This way, if both threads need authorization at the same time, one thread has to wait until the other thread has determined the credentials are good, and then it can use those credentials without prompting.

Comment: @Remy Thanks for your reply, Remy. Do you mean locking the credentials in the `OnAuthorization` event handler and unlocking after `TIdHTTP::Get()` or `TIdHTTP::Post()` returns and `ResponseCode != 401`? That could leave the credentials locked indefinitely and with it, every `OnAuthorization` handler that tries to lock them. As we discussed in another question, `TIdHTTP` only triggers `OnAuthorization` once and only if the username is blank. Also, how does the other thread determine it should not prompt but use the stored credentials? Could `TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer` solve this?

Comment: @Remy Please see the update in my original question. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "*Do you mean ...*" - yes, exactly. "*That could leave the credentials locked indefinitely*" - I don't think so. "*and with it, every OnAuthorization handler that tries to lock them*" - only authorizations in other threads, since the thread actively prompting the user would already be inside the lock, and `TCritcalSection` locks are reentrant for the same thread that has the lock. "*how does the other thread determine it should not prompt but use the stored credentials?*" - Simply don't save invalid credentials. Or else save a `boolean` alongside the credentials to say whether they are valid

Comment: *"TCritcalSection locks are reentrant for the same thread that has the lock."* I did not know that. That's why my code didn't work. I should have called `GetCreds()` directly in the thread without using `Synchronize()`. Thanks for your help, Remy.